# What is the fastest way to draw in HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, tile

I am drawing a screen to the web using javascript, CSS, and HTML by using a for loop to iterate through the screen width and heights in intervals of 16X16. Here is what my loop currently looks like:

```
{
        div = document.getElementById('mainView');
        while (div.children.length > 0)
            div.removeChild(div.children[0]);

        for (y = this.y; y < this.y + this.height; ++y)
        {
            for (x = this.x; x < this.x + this.width; ++x)
            {
                toAppend = document.createElement('div');
                viewCoords = this.convertWorldToView(x, y);
                toAppend.style.top = viewCoords[1] * 16 + 'px';
                toAppend.style.left = viewCoords[0] * 16 + 'px';
                mainViewDiv.appendChild(toAppend);
                if (fullMap[y][x] == TILE_WATER)
                {
                    startTile = Math.round(Math.random() * 3) + 1;
                    toAppend.className = "Water" + startTile + "Tile";
                }
                else
                {
                    toAppend.className = typeClassDecoder[fullMap[y][x]];
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Is there a faster way to draw all these tiles to the screen using either canvas or some of function in javascript or a blend of javascript and css?

Comment: If i get it correctly you are adding divs in tiled fashion after removing all its contents .

Comment: Without the full code and no markup/css it's hard to understand what is going on. I suggest you put your code in a jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/) and provide the link.

Comment: Example of a similar quest on jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/robhawkes/cV3Rr/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating an excessive amount of reflow/layout events by doing things this way. Since you remove all the items and then add them again (both expensive the way you're doing them), instead just add all the divs once, and since they're always in the same order, just update the existing ones.

Also, to clear a div quickly, do `div.innerHTML = '';`. If appending lots of items, add them to a dummy div and then attach the dummy div to a div actually attached to the DOM (eg, one that you can query using document.getElement??? functions).

In init:

```
div = document.getElementById('mainView');
for (y = this.y; y < this.y + this.height; ++y)
{
    for (x = this.x; x < this.x + this.width; ++x)
    {
        toAppend = document.createElement('div');
        viewCoords = this.convertWorldToView(x, y);
        toAppend.style.top = viewCoords[1] * 16 + 'px';
        toAppend.style.left = viewCoords[0] * 16 + 'px';
        mainViewDiv.appendChild(toAppend);
    }
}
```

In render:

```
div = document.getElementById('mainView');
var i = 0;

for (y = this.y; y < this.y + this.height; ++y)
{
    for (x = this.x; x < this.x + this.width; ++x)
    {
        toAppend = div.children[i++];
        if (fullMap[y][x] == TILE_WATER)
        {
            startTile = Math.round(Math.random() * 3) + 1;
            toAppend.className = "Water" + startTile + "Tile";
        }
        else
        {
            toAppend.className = typeClassDecoder[fullMap[y][x]];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you that speed things up tremendously. Do you think using a canvas would be faster? Or is there any other ways of drawing tiles like this that would be faster?

Comment: A canvas can be faster, but I wouldn't bet on it immediately. After all, class switching uses native rendering optimizations in modern browsers that javascript code + canvas won't necessarily match. I would do some quick benchmarks. As a general rule, optimization should always follow testing. In the above case, I had already tested these cases (eg, element creation, attachments, etc), but I haven't tested the canvas tiles case myself.